# Proofs' role in Coq extractions

Tags: haskell, coq, coq-extraction

I'm trying to understand what is the role of proofs in Coq extractions.
I have the following example of floor integer division by two taken from [here](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540208549). For my first try I used the `Admitted` keyword:

```
(*********************)
(* div_2_even_number *)
(*********************)
Definition div_2_even_number: forall n,
  (Nat.Even n) -> {p:nat | n=p+p}.
Proof.
Admitted.

(*************)
(* test_even *)
(*************)
Definition test_even: forall n,
  {Nat.Even n}+{Nat.Even (pred n)}.
Proof.
Admitted.

(********************)
(* div_2_any_number *)
(********************)
Definition div_2_any_number (n:nat):
  {p:nat | n = p+p}+{p:nat | (pred n) = p+p} :=
  match (test_even n) with
  | left h => inl _ (div_2_even_number n h)
  | right h' => inr _ (div_2_even_number (pred n) h')
  end.

(***************************)
(* Extract to Haskell file *)
(***************************)
Extraction "/home/oren/some_file.hs" div_2_any_number.
```

When I examine the resulting Haskell file I see that it is indeed missing:

```
div_2_even_number :: Prelude.Integer -> Prelude.Integer
div_2_even_number =
  Prelude.error "AXIOM TO BE REALIZED"

test_even :: Prelude.Integer -> Prelude.Bool
test_even =
  Prelude.error "AXIOM TO BE REALIZED"

div_2_any_number :: Prelude.Integer -> Prelude.Either Prelude.Integer
                    Prelude.Integer
div_2_any_number n =
  case test_even n of {
   Prelude.True -> Prelude.Left (div_2_even_number n);
   Prelude.False -> Prelude.Right (div_2_even_number (pred n))}
```

So I figured OK, let's prove `div_2_even_number`:

```
(*********************)
(* div_2_even_number *)
(*********************)
Definition div_2_even_number: forall n,
  (Nat.Even n) -> {p:nat | n=p+p}.
Proof.
  intros n0 H.
  unfold Nat.Even in H.
  destruct H as [m0].
  exists m0.
Qed.
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: Case analysis on sort Set is not allowed for inductive definition ex.
```

What's going on here? I'm obviously missing something here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though what chi said is correct, in this case you can actually extract the witness `p` from the existence proof.  When you have a boolean predicate `P : nat -> bool`, if `exists p, P p = true`, you can compute some `p` that satisfies the predicate by running the following function from 0:

```
find p := if P p then p else find (S p)
```

You cannot write this function directly in Coq, but it is possible to do so by crafting a special inductive proposition.  This pattern is implemented in the [choice module](https://math-comp.github.io/math-comp/htmldoc/mathcomp.ssreflect.choice.html) of the mathematical components library:

```
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool ssrnat eqtype choice.

(* == is the boolean equality test *)
Definition even n := exists p, (n == 2 * p) = true.

Definition div_2_even_number n (nP : even n) : {p | (n == 2 * p) = true} :=
  Sub (xchoose nP) (xchooseP nP).
```

The `xchoose : (exists n, P n = true) -> nat` function performs the above search, and `xchooseP` shows that the its result satisfies the boolean predicate. (The actual types are more general than this, but when instantiated to `nat` they yield this signature.)  I have used the boolean equality operator to simplify the code, but it would have been possible to use `=` instead.

That being said, if you care about running your code, programming in this fashion is terribly inefficient: you need to perform `n / 2` `nat` comparisons to test divide `n`.  It is much better to write a simply typed version of the division function:

```
Fixpoint div2 n :=
  match n with
  | 0 | 1 => 0
  | S (S n) => S (div2 n)
  end.
```

Answer (score 6):

You are working with types in different sorts.

```
> Check (Nat.Even 8).
Nat.Even 8
     : Prop

> Check {p:nat | 8=p+p}.
{p : nat | 8 = p + p}
     : Set
```

A feature of the Coq type system is that you can not eliminate a value whose type is in `Prop` to obtain something whose type is not in `Prop` (roughly -- some exception is done by Coq for `Prop` types which carry no information, like `True` and `False`, but we are not in that case). Roughly put you can not use a proof of a proposition for anything but to prove another proposition.

This limitation is unfortunately required to allow `Prop` to be impredicative (we want `forall P: Prop, P->P` to be a type in sort `Prop`) and to be consistent with the law of excluded middle. We can not have everything or we meet Berardi's paradox.

Comment: Can you really not, for example, use `Prop` information to show that a case you've reached is impossible when constructing a `Type`?

Comment: @luqui I can't recall, but I think Coq indeed does an exception for inductive types having zero or one trivial constructors, since they carry no "data". A quick experiment seems to confirm this.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, does it mean that `div_2_even_number` can **not** be proved? is there any way to define (and extract) `div_2_any_number`?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom how is `Nat.Even` defined?

Comment: `div_2_even_number` can be proved, but not directly from the `Nat.Even` assumption. Think of what it would extract to: if you erase the proofs (`Nat.Even` and `n = p + p`) you are left with a function `nat -> nat`, which should map even numbers to their halves, and which will never be applied to odd numbers (because they do not have proofs of `Nat.Even` in the source language). Therefore `div_2_even_number` has to do at least as much computation as a division by two to construct the result `p : nat`, plus potentially additional work to construct the proof term for `n = p + p`.

Comment: @chi is correct, if the expected type is of sort `Type`, you can only destruct proof terms which are noninformative, and that allows you to destruct proofs of `False` in "impossible cases".

Comment: @luqui here it is: `Nat.Even = fun n : nat => exists m : nat, n = 2 * m
     : nat -> Prop`