# Have problem with unable to use destruct tatic in a Definition

Tags: coq, coqide

I am working with a definition in coq which need to yield something from a Theorem, but cannot destruct in the definition.

```
Theorem sp : forall (X : Type) (T : X -> Prop)..... , exists (a : X), T a.
Definition yield_sp : (X : Type) (T : X -> Prop) (H : sp X T .....)..... : X.
```

When I try to destruct H, coq warns that

> Case analysis on sort Type is not allowed for inductive definition ex.

I would like to know the reason for it, and further, how to use definition to yield an element from an "exists" proposition.

Comment: I guess a colon is missing after `Theorem sp`?

Comment: yes, I mess it up with Definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot extract the witness out of an existence proof.  There are a few options:

- Change the statement of the proof to `{x : T | P x}`, which behaves more-or-less like the existential quantifier, but supports a projection function `proj1_sig : {x : T | P x} -> T`.
- Assume a choice axiom, as in https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.ClassicalChoice.html
- If you are quantifying over a countable type *and* your proposition is decidable, you can use the trick in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55862398/proofs-role-in-coq-extractions) to extract the witness.

Comment: Is it a syntax of coq that to yield something simply from an exists statement is not allowed? I think that to do so one has to declare that there is a projection function that exactly can **compute** it since arrow means computable relation in coq.