# Why unable to perform case analysis in rather simple case

Tags: coq, ssreflect

Well, the code

```
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect ssrnat ssrbool eqtype.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Inductive nat_rels m n : bool -> bool -> bool -> Set :=
| CompareNatLt of m < n : nat_rels m n true false false
| CompareNatGt of m > n : nat_rels m n false true false
| CompareNatEq of m == n : nat_rels m n false false true.

Lemma natrelP m n : nat_rels m n (m < n) (m > n) (m == n).
Proof.
  case (leqP m n); case (leqP n m).
  move => H1 H2; move: (conj H1 H2) => {H1} {H2} /andP.
  rewrite -eqn_leq => /eqP /ssrfun.esym /eqP H.
    by rewrite H; constructor.
  move => H. rewrite leq_eqVlt => /orP. 
  case.
```

Error is `Error: Case analysis on sort Set is not allowed for inductive definition or.`
The last goal before the `case` is

```
  m, n : nat
  H : m < n
  ============================
  m == n \/ m < n -> nat_rels m n true false (m == n)
```

I've already used this construction (`rewrite leq_eqVlt => /orP; case`) in very similar situation and it just worked:

```
Lemma succ_max_distr n m : (maxn n m).+1 = maxn (n.+1) (m.+1).
Proof.
  wlog : m n / m < n => H; last first.
  rewrite max_l /maxn; last by exact: ltnW.
  rewrite leqNgt.
  have: m.+1 < n.+2 by apply: ltnW.
    by move => ->.
    case: (leqP n m); last by apply: H.
  rewrite leq_eqVlt => /orP.  case.
```

1. What is the difference between two cases?
2. and Why "Case analysis on sort Set is not allowed for inductive definition or"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the two cases is the sort of the goal (Set vs Prop) when you execute the `case` command. In the first situation your goal is `nat_rels ...` and you declared that inductive in `Set`; in the second situation your goal is an equality that lands in `Prop`.

The reason why you can't do a case analysis on `\/` when the goal is in `Set` (the first situation) is because `\/` has been declared as `Prop`-valued. The main restriction associated to such a declaration is that you cannot use informative content from a `Prop` to build something in `Set` (or more generally `Type`), so that `Prop` is compatible with an erasure-semantic at extraction time.

In particular, doing a case analysis on `\/` gives away the side of the `\/` that is valid, and you can't be allowed to use that information for building some data in `Set`.

You have at least two solutions at your disposal:

1. You could move your family `nat_rels` from `Set` to `Prop` if that's compatible with what you want to do later on.
2. Or you could use the fact that the hypothesis that you want to branch on is decidable and find a way to produce some `{m == n} + { m <n }` out of `m <= n`; here the notation `{ _ } + { _ }` is the `Set`-valued disjunction of proposition.

Comment: Do I understand it right: There is no such limitation in theory. But the coq developers decided go this way because it has some technical advantages. ?

Comment: @Andrey It's a real limitation in the theory, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55868122/2747511